# Different title for homepage and single posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically I want to display a different title for my homepage and single posts.

Right now I have this code in the header.php:

`<title> <?php wp_title('', true,''); ?>  (<?php the_time( 'Y/m/d' ); ?>)- <?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>  </title>`

This displays my post title, post date and my blog name.

**How to make a coffee (2021/02/05) - My Coffee Blog**

But when I go to my home page, it displays date first (which I don't need) and only then my blog name.

**(2021/02/05) - My Coffee Blog**

Is there any way to control which ones to output for homepage, posts and pages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use is_front_page().

Something like this should work:

```
<title>  
  <?php 
    if (!(is_front_page())) {
      wp_title('', true,''); ?>  (<?php the_time( 'Y/m/d' ); ?>)- 
    <?php }
  echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>  
</title>
```

Comment: Getting an error... Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 174 of file wp-content/themes/yoneko/header.php. Please fix and try saving again.

syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: yep, mine should be good now, fixed a missing open PHP statement

Comment: Awesome!, your worked actually better than mine, because I can include brackets () and other characters using your code.

I have one more question. Now that I added my own <title></title> in the header.php, when I click on view source code, I can see two titles. The first is mine that I manually added and another one is Wordpresse's default. Is there any option to remove Wordpresses default code through functions.php? Thanks!

Comment: The example on this page looks good, so I'd just plugin my code above into the example filter.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/

Also, can you accept my answer as valid?

Comment: Found the solution! This code in functions.php worked: remove_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1 ); As for accepting your answer, I'm afraid I don't have enough reputation to do that here on stackoverflow... I would if I could. Thanks for your efforts, Peter!

Comment: You should be able to click the check I think.  As a new user, you just can't upvote if I'm remembering right.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working solution. Peter's code worked great. Add this to header.php:

```
<title>  
  <?php 
    if (!(is_front_page())) {
      wp_title('', true,''); ?>  (<?php the_time( 'Y/m/d' ); ?>)- 
    <?php }
  echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>  
</title>
```

If you view your source code now, you will see two titles. Your newly added and the default Wordpress.

To remove the default Wordpress title, just paste this code to your functions.php:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1 );
```

Wualla! Now you have your custom title.